# Django Views saving data on application start

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I have a weird issue I can't seem to figure out. Relatively new to django and python, but this is my 3rd of 4th project. With this project I have a view that refreshes a database by making about 400 http requests. It takes a while, but that's fine, it's only called rarely. 
My issue is that whenever I start my application that view, which accesses code stored in another imported module, does it's thing. It's making all of those requests. It's saving all of that data. Every single time I start my server and make a request to the root page. I feel like I'm missing something very very obvious here, but I'm self-taught and am extremely stumped. I've linked my github for his project, but I'll also include some of the important bits.
https://github.com/heymanitsmematt/CalledIt

---API urls.py that I think is causing everything to run slow

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from views import UpdateMensNCAABasketball
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns = patterns('api/',
    (r'^ncaabball/$', UpdateMensNCAABasketball.as_view())
)
```

-- the API view that does the heavy lifting

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from app.models import User, Sport, Event, Party, Prediction
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, View, ListView
from django.http import HttpResponse
import simplejson
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.core import serializers
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
import requests
from NCAABBallScraper import Scraper, ScheduleScraper
from app.models import Sport, Team, Event, User, Party, Prediction


months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'
months = months.split()
def monthGetter(month, months):
    i=1
    for m in months:
    if month == m:
        return i
    else: i += 1

class updateNcaaMensBasketball(View):
    sport = Sport.objects.get_or_create(sport = 'Ncaa Mens Basketball')[0]
    sport.save()
    scraper = Scraper()
    scraper.parse()
    schedScraper = ScheduleScraper(scraper.teams)
```

--My main application view, where i want empty urls to redirect

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from app.views import Main 
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', Main.as_view()),
)
```

--The main project urls dispatch file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from app import urls
from api import urls


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'calledit.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^', include(app.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include(api.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Ignore the naming on import issues, that's been fixed

Answer (score 2):

Code in updateNcaaMensBasketball view class must be in 'post' or 'get' method or just use function-base views.

In your case code in class executed every time then class was imported.

Sorry for my English

[Django CBV docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/intro/)

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks a lot, class based views are a lot tougher than function based views.